# Using https with IdentityServer4 quickstart hangs

Tags: https, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to learn IdentityServer4 so I started with the documentation here https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/0_overview.html and ended with this https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html.

Everything works great as long as I use http, but as soon as I switch to using https, the very first line of code in the client tester

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44384");
```

hangs and eventually gets a task cancelled exception.

If I just switch everything back to http, it starts working again.

In the actual IdentityServer solution, I changed applicationUrl and launchUrl in launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44384/",
      "sslPort": 44384
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Mvcg.IdentityServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44384",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And .UseUrls in Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseUrls("https://localhost:44384")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

In the client solution, as noted in above, I changed the code that is calling the discovery endpoint to use https instead of http

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:44384");
```

To be clear, simply changing all of the noted items from between http and https works for http but not for https.  Nothing else changes between my two tests.

Is there something I am missing causing the https to not work?

Comment: What happens when you access the site and the discovery document in the browser? any asp.net logs that give you a hint (crank up the log level to trace)

Comment: After starting the solution in Visual Studio, I went to https://localhost:44384/.well-known/openid-configuration in my browser and it just says "This site can't be reached.  localhost took too long to respond."  Developer tools shows ERR_TIMED_OUT.  Interestingly enough, I downloaded the samples from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples and tried the same test.  I switched from http to https and the same thing happened.  I will look into the logs to see if there is any help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with console hosting.  As long as I run the IdentityServer host in IIS Express, everything works fine.  Every time I try to switch it to console hosting, it fails.  The error displayed in the hosting console is:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
      Connection id "0HKVQ4SEO0GOI" bad request data: "The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters."
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Infrastructure.MemoryPoolIteratorExtensions.GetAsciiString(MemoryPoolIterator start, MemoryPoolIterator end)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.TakeStartLine(SocketInput input)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Connection processing ended abnormally
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.BadHttpRequestException: The input string contains non-ASCII or null characters.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Infrastructure.MemoryPoolIteratorExtensions.GetAsciiString(MemoryPoolIterator start, MemoryPoolIterator end)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame.TakeStartLine(SocketInput input)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Not sure exactly how to fix that error so for now, I am just going to have to host in IIS Express to keep moving forward.

Comment: And the answer to the issue is that IIS Express uses a development certificate for https whereas Kestrel does not.  If you want to use console hosting with https, you need a certificate.  https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Startup.cs#L37-L43